# codeigniter thumbnail creation

Tags: codeigniter

what should be the height and width i should specify while creating thumbnail for my profile image. I show the thumbnail with a 40px * 40px image container

Comment: how is this specifically related to Codeigniter? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @ShiVik - Am using codeigniter image manipulation gallery to create thumbnail. so am specifying thumbnail height and width for the image

Comment: I did not get where you are stuck? Are you having problem in creating the thumbnail or do you just want to know about the preferable size of thumbnail? If its latter - its not a question basically, its a matter of choice - ain't it?

Comment: i gave 100 * 100 (height * width )...but certain images are streched when i display images in a 40 by 40 container. what should i do

Comment: Why are you putting 100x100 images in a 40 by 40 container? The problem could be that the images are disproportionate.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, there's `maintain_ratio` and `master_dim` settings. Here's what the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html) says about the `master_dim` setting:

> Specifies what to use as the master
>   axis when resizing or creating thumbs.
>   For example, let's say you want to
>   resize an image to 100 X 75 pixels. If
>   the source image size does not allow
>   perfect resizing to those dimensions,
>   this setting determines which axis
>   should be used as the hard value.
>   "auto" sets the axis automatically
>   based on whether the image is taller
>   then wider, or vice versa.